# download files from a dropbox folder

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api

I'm using node.js and the dropbox package to download files from a folder. I'm able to authenticate and list the files, but not downloading them. I'd like to be able to download none shared files as well.

```
       client.filesListFolder({ path: directory })
    .then(function (response) {
        response.entries.forEach(function (entry) {
            if (entry[".tag"] === "file") {
                client.filesDownload({ url: entry.path_display})
                    .then(function (data) {
                        // ...
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        throw err;
                    });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      me.ThrowError(null, err.status, err.error);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're using [dropbox-sdk-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) and have already found the [`filesDownload`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload) method. What isn't working exactly? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this link:
https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-api-v2/

filesDownload({ url: entry.path_display}) passed a wrong arg.

I think it should be {path: entry.path_display}

I actually just tried it, but I only get the file object, I don't know how to get the file data be downloaded. It is may be because I am using Electron.js

As discussed in their github issue:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/88

Therefore, you could try to use function `filesGetTemporaryLink({ path: entry.path_display})`to a temp link and then use `sharingGetSharedLinkFile({ url: res.link })`